# objective-c memory management issue in iPhone

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

i am new to iphone development, i am facing memory leak in following code

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
if(!currentNodeContent)
    currentNodeContent = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string] autorelease];
else
    [currentNodeContent appendString:string];
}
```

i have received 100% memory leak in this code when analysing with instrument tool

```
currentNodeContent = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string] autorelease];
```

Can any one suggest me the way to solve this leak

Comment: did you already alloc and init currentNodeContent in any other method?

Comment: This is the obligatory "Use ARC" comment.

Comment: @MikeWeller why? There are many projects that don't use ARC and they are perfectly legit to be that way...

Comment: If you are writing new code, there is very little reason not to use ARC. ARC works with non-ARC code, and works all the way back to iOS 4.2 (minus weak refs).

Comment: Where is the declaration for currentNodeContent. Is it a property? If yes do you have retain associated with it?

Comment: yes i alloc currentNodeContent in -(void)parser :(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict { if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"tagname"]) {
        currentNodeContent=[[[NSMutableString alloc]init] autorelease];
    }
}

Comment: We need to see the declaration of `currentNodeContent` and any other code where `currentNodeContent` is referenced. The code you've posted so far doesn't show a leak.

Comment: BTW, I hate to mention this for fear of further confusing the issue (and it's unrelated to your leak), but it's not prudent to make `currentNodeObject` an `autorelease` object. It makes it contingent on internal implementation details of `NSXMLParser` and when it drains the pool. You really should be creating a non-`autorelease` object with a +1 `retainCount` in `foundCharacters`, and after `didEndElement` saves the object wherever you want to store it, only then should you `[currentNodeContent release]`. You also minimize your app's memory high-water mark that way.

Answer (score 0):

Instruments is great at finding what objects leaked. It isn't so good at telling you the source of the leak. If this is object leaking, it's not because of this code, but rather somewhere else in your code, you've retained this `currentNodeContent` (perhaps added it to some other data structure that never released it).

The static analyzer (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or choosing "Analyze" on the Xcode "Product" menu) sometimes can identify sources of leaks. I'd make sure you get a clean bill of health there before even bothering with Instruments.

If you are still leaking, I'd look at what you did with `currentNodeContent` in `didEndElement`, and look at your memory management from that point on.

You can also look at the [Finding Leaks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/developertools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW4) section of the *Instruments User Guide* and see other suggestions (for example, the "Cycles and Roots", discussed there, might help you follow  the object graph for this leaked object).

Answer (score 0):

replace this line as `currentNodeContent = [string mutablecopy];` and see if this works out.

Comment: No offense, but that's not a good idea. It doesn't solve the problem, but introduces another problem: If the XML element contents was a long string, requiring multiple calls to `foundCharacters`, you'd be discarding the previous contents, in effect only returning the last portion of the element's value.